# Ignore empty elements of bash indexed array

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm filtering `PATH` variables, such that certain elements are deleted (in the example below, it's elements containing the string `x86`; in practice I'm looking for the string `site-packages`):

```
$ echo $(IFS=:;arr=($PATH);echo "${arr[*]//*x86*}")
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live::/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Lenovo Fingerprint Reader:::/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:::::/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Lenovo:::/cygdrive/c/SWTOOLS/ReadyApps:::::/usr/lib/lapack
```

This works pretty well, except that all of the elements which have been zeroed out are still, there, but empty. I'd like to end up with those elements eliminated, and I don't want to use anything other than bash to do it (I know I can use `tr`, but for portability reasons I would strongly prefer a bash-only solution).

Here's the tr-based solution:

```
echo $(IFS=:;arr=($PATH);echo "${arr[*]//*x86*}" | tr -s :)
```

Update: I'm using arrays because I want to be robust in the face of spaces (or anything else other than colons) in the path elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to be more explicit about it:

```
PATH=$(
  IFS=:
  new=()
  for p in $PATH; do
    [[ $p != *x86* ]] && new+=("$p")
  done
  echo "${new[*]}"
)
```

It's more verbose, but correct and bash-only as requested

Comment: Thanks. More concise than my approach involving building up a new array after filtering.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't require an explicit loop, but might be a bit fragile. It uses a backspace to "unwrite" the colon preceding a directory to remove, and it requires special handling if the first or last directory in `PATH` is removed.

```
echo $(IFS=:;
       arr=($PATH);
       # When finally echoed, any \b character will remove
       # the preceding colon from the output.
       new="${arr[*]//*x86*/$'\b'}";
       # Remove :\b if last directory was removed
       new=${new%:$'\b'};
       # Remove \b: if first directory was removed
       echo "${new#$'\b':}")
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which builds up a contiguous array using a loop:

```
$ echo $(IFS=:;arr=($PATH);sqarr="${arr[*]//*x86*}";declare -a finalarr; for item in $sqarr; do [[ $item ]] && finalarr+=("$item"); done; echo "${finalarr[*]}")
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Lenovo Fingerprint Reader:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Lenovo:/cygdrive/c/SWTOOLS/ReadyApps:/usr/lib/lapack
```

Across multiple lines:

```
$(
  IFS=:
  arr=($PATH)
  sqarr="${arr[*]//*x86*}"
  declare -a finalarr
  for item in $sqarr; do 
      [[ $item ]] && finalarr+=("$item")
  done 
  echo "${finalarr[*]}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) assuming `PATH` constituents do not contain spaces, so definitely more fragile than the other solutions. The empty array elements are discarded at the point of `arr2` assignment

```
echo $(IFS=:;arr=($PATH);unset IFS;arr2=(${arr[@]//*x86*});IFS=:;echo "${arr2[*]}")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using arrays specifically because I want to be robust in the face of spaces. Sorry for not mentioning that.